# Magento 2 Order Collection + Customer Collection

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to make a PHP file to get Orders and Customers from a Magento 2 based webshop (like exporting). I have a full code for Magento 1, but for M2 I have tried a lot of things.

I also needed this function for Products but now I have this.

If anybody can add a full code for Orders and Customers I would be glad, if I found one I will paste it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi to get order collection in magento 2 you can use the below code

```
 $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
     foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
     print_r($orderDatamodel1->getData());

     }
```

you can get the order items from the order by using

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
     foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
     $getid =  $orderDatamodel1->getData("increment_id");
         $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($getid);
          //echo "<pre>";
          $getorderdata = $orderData->getData();
          $orderItems = $orderData->getAllVisibleItems();
          foreach($orderItems as $orderItems){
                    print_r($orderItems->getData());
        }
     }
```

for more information check this http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2016/10/how-to-get-order-collection-in-magento2.html

Comment: Please provide the option we can use Thanks

Comment: A forward slash is missing before Magento, and using object manager is not a good practice, instead of this model instance can be injected in controller constructor.

Answer (score 1):

to get customer collection and there data you can use

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection();
 foreach($customerObj as $customerObjdata ){
     print_r($customerObjdata ->getData());

     }
```